# Update Profiles in APEX

Tags: apex, metadata-api, postinstall

Anything I've read indicates that there's no native APEX DDL layer for Metadata such as Profiles. It seems the only way to update profiles in Apex is to use [FinancialForce's MDAPI wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/).

This is all OK, it's working fine.

But now I need to be able to run it an part of a package post-installation process (an APEX class implementing InstallHandler)

The trouble here is that MDAPI wrapper uses `UserInfo.getSession()` to get a session ID, which I cannot do here.

Any other way of updating Profiles within a post-installation script?

Comment: I can't guarantee this will work, but I found a way you might be able to get a session Id. You need this page: `<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" 
           applyBodyTag="false" contentType="text/plain">{!$Api.Session_ID}
    #
</apex:page>` (insert a new line before the #), which allows you to call this code: `String sessionId = Page.sessionId.getContent().toString().split('\n',2)u[0];` I tested this in a future call, and it gave me a valid session Id. You can try this and let me know?

Comment: That `u` somehow managed to sneak in before the `[0]`, and I'm past the edit time for the comment. Feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in the context of InstallHandler. I think to do a `Page.xxx.getContent()` might be a callout, which requires a sessionId. So to get a sessionId this way, I need a sessionId. Catch-22.